# Display of full calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

How can I change the display of full calendar where by time appears horizontally at the top and events displayed vertically.

Prompt response would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

fullCalendar does not have this feature as far as I know. It'll take some pretty significant re-writing of the plugin to do so.

Comment: Hi,

Is there any other calendar in which is similar and I can achieve the same.

Comment: I just looked through a bunch of calendars with agendas and the only one I could find that does it is web2cal (http://web2cal.com/ajaxeventscalendar/calendar-demo/912-premium-demo/96-premium-workshift-view)... but I haven't tested or looked at it's functionality at all, It that isn't what you want, then I would suggest putting in a feature request (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/support/) - you never know :)